# Component testcomp installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file

Tags: wix

I'd like to copy a file under a Doucments location in WiX. But it gives the warning:

> Component testcomp installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.

My code:

```
<Directory Id='PersonalFolder' Name='MyDocuments'>
   <Component Id='testcomp' Guid='08C288B6-D8E0-4036-9CEB-E5F616AC6B5C'>
      <File Id='doc_code_file1' Name='doc_code_file1' DiskId='1'
            Source='Personalfolder\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\SimpleMvvm\mvvmcommand.snippet' KeyPath='yes'></File>
   </Component>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's correct. The Windows Installer wants registry keys as the key paths for per-user Components. It has to do with the way profiles work with advertised content in enterprise deployments. The fix is very straight forward:

```
<Directory Id='PersonalFolder' Name='MyDocuments'>
   <Component Id='testcomp' Guid='08C288B6-D8E0-4036-9CEB-E5F616AC6B5C'>

      <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Manufacturer\Product'
                     Name='Something (I like to use InstallFolder)'
                     Value='Something (I like to use [INSTALLFOLDER]'
                     Type='string'
                     KeyPath='yes' />

      <File Id='doc_code_file1' Name='doc_code_file1' DiskId='1'
            Source='Personalfolder\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\SimpleMvvm\mvvmcommand.snippet' />
   </Component>
</Directory>
```

Note: The added per-user registry key and that it is marked `KeyPath='yes'`. The latter is not explicitly necessary since it's the first resource in the Component which will be marked as the key path by default, but being explicit with the key path is sometimes better.

Comment: The existing warning was disappear. But It gives a new warning "warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file 'doc_code_file1' will be installed to the per user directory 'code_SimpleMvvm' that doesn't vary based on ALLUSERS value. This file won't be copied to each user's profile even if a per machine installation is desired". What could be a problem?

Comment: That's great coz this means we have to add keys for every component, and the official recommendation is to make every file a component. Meaning we gotta create regkeys for EVERY FILE. WHAT THE HELL.

Comment: What will happen if i used the same <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Manufacturer\Product' Name='' Value='' Type='string' KeyPath='yes'/> for all files so i can have only one reg key??

Comment: @ElamirOhana you will violate the [Component Rules](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/component-rules-101/). Net result, reference counting will be completely off.

Comment: @RobMensching I'm new to Wix
And what will be the side effect of that?

Comment: @ElamirOhana read the blog entry I provided. It gives you "mathematical proofs" that demonstrate the problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobMensching

Comment: Why can't Wix automate this??  I know nothing about the registry.

Comment: We could but you'd magically be getting registry keys added to your installation package that you did not code in. That (historically) isn't something the WiX Toolset does (aka: adding stuff that you didn't ask for).

Additionally, there are non-pathological cases (and some really nasty pathological cases) that require de-duping.

However, the WiX Toolset has been getting smarter as versions go along and more comfortable solving some of these problems for the developer automagically.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `Suppress ICE validation` option, Visual studio will ignore these validations

Just follow this route:
`YourProject` -> `Properties` -> `Tool Settings`

[image: ICE validation]

Comment: But, is this approach just fine? I mean, all my errors are gone though.