# C# Installer without need of admin context

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I'm looking for a way to create an Installer for my Solution. 
I found several ways to do this
1. ClickOne Publish - which I cant use because I need the Installer Dialog
2. Microsoft Installer - which is always asking to elevate the installing  process
3. WiX Installer - which drives me into despair

To Way 2.
I created an Installer which is all I need, but it requieres Admin Rights.

To Way 3. 
I tried to change the Directory to [AppDataFolder]/Timestamp which brings me tons of errors.

> Error ICE64: The directory AppRootDirectory is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
>   Error ICE38: Component Timestamp.exe installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a
>   file.
>   Error ICE38: Component de_DE_Timestamp.resources.dll installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
>   ErrorICE64: The directory de_DE is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table. 
>   Error ICE38:Component Timestamp.exe.config installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
>   Error ICE38: Component Newtonsoft.Json.dll installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define Timestamp_TargetDir=$(var.Timestamp.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="Timestamp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="BASF Business Services GmbH" UpgradeCode="0b61a75c-dcc0-4041-a1a6-2b68491bda66">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Timestamp" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="de_DE_files" />
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="AppRootDirectory_files" />
        </Feature>
        <UI />
        <Icon Id="timestampIcon.ico" SourceFile="C:\Users\StaebP\Downloads\timestampIcon.ico" />

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes"/>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder" Name="AppData">
          <Directory Id="AppRootDirectory" Name="Timestamp">
            <Directory Id="de_DE" Name="de-DE" />
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Fragment>



  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="de_DE_files" Directory="de_DE">
      <Component Id="de_DE_Timestamp.resources.dll" Guid="9e6ba90d-7e16-4f13-be70-2ed90f55417d">
        <File Id="de_DE_Timestamp.resources.dll" Name="Timestamp.resources.dll" Source="$(var.Timestamp_TargetDir)de-DE\Timestamp.resources.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="AppRootDirectory_files" Directory="AppRootDirectory">
      <Component Id="Timestamp.exe" Guid="eed65b62-9fb3-4dbd-a7c2-96615a7566b2">
        <File Id="Timestamp.exe" Name="Timestamp.exe" Source="$(var.Timestamp_TargetDir)Timestamp.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Timestamp.exe.config" Guid="41c099c6-00ff-49a6-813e-9fbde4689171">
        <File Id="Timestamp.exe.config" Name="Timestamp.exe.config" Source="$(var.Timestamp_TargetDir)Timestamp.exe.config" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Guid="2c9c8aec-235f-4920-9f06-fb458ff86f03">
        <File Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="$(var.Timestamp_TargetDir)Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: To keep your sanity just use the Package an Deployment Wizard in VS2013 and above. Or Nullsoft (NSIS), Install Shield, WiSE, etc.

Comment: Install Shield needs Admin Rights aswell :(

Comment: That's right, these days it's common to create base installers (VB, JRE, .Net framework) that come with SOEs. Then you can deploy packages that don't require Admin, like Chrome. If you don't have SOEs because this software is public facing, and it requires Program Files, Registry, Services then there is no silver bullet

Comment: I'm pretty shure my tool don't make changes to the system. The clickonce publisher won't need admin rights

Comment: Just work through the ICE errors one by one.  You'll find answers to each of them on SO: [ICE64](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4627861/4267590), [ICE38](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16119708/4267590), etc.